# How to model window into wall

Tags: modeling

I have an architectural scene that I imported from 3ds max, however there is no windows in walls. Problem is, the scene doesn't have strict scale (I don't know measurements of the holes).

How this problem should be approached, because there is quite a few windows in my scene.

Comment: More information is needed. Windows? Scale?

Comment: What is "strict scale"? It's not really clear what your problem is, are you asking how to model hole for the window from scratch or build already existing window into the wall? Please show some screenshots and if possible reference image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just scale things properly and use Archimesh's windows. (Blender 2.78c comes with latter and you just need to enable it in User Preferences -> Add-ons.)